# Is there a way to associate and execute protractor tests to MTM test cases?

Tags: visual-studio, protractor, mtm

Here's the background:

- I've wrote my tests in protractor@visual studio and got it running successfully with the help of this [guide](https://misaxionsoftware.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/angularjs-protractor-visual-studio-super-dry/);
- Checked the project into TFS;

Now, my intention is to associate my protractor tests to microsoft case tests, then i intent to run against a environment (SCVMM).

I tried Coded Ui Test, but i found then a little bit slow.

Is there a way that i can get this done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was use [Generic Tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182626.aspx) to accomplish this.

Each Generic Test you create can represent a Protractor test. I just named them similarly. Then you can [link the Generic Test to the MTM test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx#linkGen). Simple as that.

I took it a step further and set the Generic Test up in such a way that it runs the Protractor test. This is really nice because Visual studio will recognize these tests in Test Explorer. So no more command prompt :)

Here's an example of one of mine:

[image]